# Doctrine2 generate:entities on subclass replicates parent class methods and properties

Tags: php, inheritance, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I started using symfony2 and doctrine not long ago. I have two classes (subclass and parent class) with a JOINED inheritance type. The connection seems to work fine but if I run
`doctrine:generate:entities`
on the subclass then Doctrine adds all of the parent class methods and properties to it. Moreover, they are all declared as `private`, despite them being `protected` in the parent class.

I do not want to add all that stuff to the subclass for a few reasons. Mainly:

- doctrine itself complains about this setup, saying that the `protected` symbols cannot be redeclared as `private`. This prevents the generation of the SQL.

  I am likely to need to change some of those methods in the parent class and do want the modifications to carry over to the subclass.

So the questions are:

1. Is this behavior normal or is it because of a mistake that I have made?
2. How do I stop doctrine to do that? I could just not run `doctrine:generate:entities` again on that class but I do appreciate the other stuff it does.
3. Is this a design pattern that I am not aware of? If so I am very curious about what it is good for and would be delighted to know more about it.

Thanks to everybody!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have encountered a limitation of Doctrine, the entity generator cannot generate entities with inheritance, as [mentioned in the FAQ](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/faq.html#why-does-the-entitygenerator-not-generate-inheritance-correctly). You will have to edit them manually.